# combine binded item and expression in angular js

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angular

In HTML:

```
<ul class="list-group">
   <li ng-repeat="item in simpleListVM.datasource track by $index" class="list-group-item">
      <simple-list-items listitem="item" listitemid="{{item.data.name + $index + 1}}"></simple-list-items>
   </li>
</ul>
```

In Directive:

```
scope: {
    listitem: '=',               
    listitemid:'&'                   
}
```

When I run the application it shows error.

> Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{item.data.name +$index + 1}}] starting at [{item.data.name +$index + 1}}].

Comment: Is that the  line the error points to? but it has an array in the error, but not in the question?

Comment: please create a demo with the issue you are facing will help understand you problem easily.

Comment: Yes simpleListVM.datasource is array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because the `listitemid` you provided is an interpolated expression and should be a function as defined by `listitemid: '&'`.

To me it seems you want to change `listitemid: '&'` to `listitemid: '@'`. This will bind to the result of the expression.

Comment: No problem @user2323308. Glad to help

Answer (score 0):

Stephen J Barker is right, please check my example code,

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="plunker">

<head>
  <script data-require="angular.js@1.4.x" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.4.12/angular.js" data-semver="1.4.9"></script>
</head>

<body ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <ul class="list-group">
    <li ng-repeat="item in simpleListVM.datasource track by $index" class="list-group-item">
      <simple-list-items listitem="item" listitemid="{{item.name + $index + 1}}"></simple-list-items>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
<script>
  var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {

    $scope.simpleListVM = {};
    $scope.simpleListVM.datasource = [{
      'name': 'test1'
    }, {
      'name': 'test2'
    }, {
      'name': 'test1'
    }];

  }).directive("simpleListItems", function() {
    var dir = {};
    dir.scope = {
      listitem: '=',
      listitemid: '@'
    };
    dir.link = function(s, e, a) {
      console.log("listitem", s.listitem);
      console.log("listitemid", s.listitemid);
    }
    return dir;
  });
</script>

</html>
```